# Use caffeine cache instance in a separate java class/file?

Tags: java, caffeine-cache

Is there a way to use the same instance of a cache in a different file? When I create a cache in `Main.java`, and write it like this:

```java
public class Main {
   public Cache<String, String> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
      .expireAfterWrite(2, TimeUnit.HOURS)
      .maximumSize(250)
      .build();
  public static void main(String[] args) {

  }
}
```

And want to access it from another class located in a separate file, how would I go about that?

I think it would just be the following code (`Second.java`)

```java
import Main;
public class Second {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Main main = new Main();
     main.cache.put('key', 'value');
  }
}
```

But the problem is that it creates a new instance of the Main class, hence creating a new cache. Because in `Main.java`, when the following code is executed it produces `null`.

```java
public class Main {
   public Cache<String, String> cache = Caffeine.newBuilder()
      .expireAfterWrite(2, TimeUnit.HOURS)
      .maximumSize(250)
      .build();
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //A key/value is created in Second.java
    cache.getIfPresent('key'); // => 'null'
  }
}
```

By the way I'm making an **event-driven** Minecraft plugin so the `key`/`value` should already be created via a command.

Comment: As an object instance, you can provide it however best fits your application. It is common to use a dependency injection framework like Spring or [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/GettingStarted) to configure and inject into another object's constructor. Maybe a more background is needed to answer this as I feel its overly broad.

Comment: You just need to make a class that holds the cache in a field.

Comment: You are showing 2 main methods, if they are run separately in two JVMs, there's no way to use a shared memory cache. (I mean you'd have to use another cache system)

Comment: @GaëlJ do you know another cache system that can do what I want?